# Html create table with varying length (preferred in flask)

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I want to get data from a database and import it into table in a website. Let's say there are 50 rows in sql db. then there must be 50 table rows in the table. But when I try to create a table, i must add each rows and cols by tags by manual. So should i add tens of thsounds rows and make this happen by controlling their visibility? I currently use flask but if there is no way to achieve it by flask, other ways are accepted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flask, you can dynamically generate an HTML table with varying length based on the data from your SQL database. You don't need to manually create thousands of rows and control their visibility. Instead, you can use a template engine, which is integrated into Flask, to achieve this easily.
Hope this will help you

Retrieve the data from your SQL database: Use Flask's database integration to fetch the data from your database.

Pass the data to the template: In your Flask route, pass the data retrieved from the database as a variable to the HTML template.

Use templating: In your HTML template, use syntax to loop through the data and dynamically generate the table rows and cells.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

# Replace this with your database connection and query code to fetch data
# For demonstration purposes, let's assume you have fetched data in the 'rows' variable
rows = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'John', 'age': 25},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Jane', 'age': 30},
    # Add more rows as needed
]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('table_template.html', rows=rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Table</title>
    <style>
        /* Add border to the table */
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        /* Add bold font style to the header row */
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        /* Add border to table cells (optional) */
        td, th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for row in rows %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.age }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```